# How to join two tables on mysql or php with multiple condition

Tags: mysql

Table 1: project_list

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | A |
| 6 | B |
| 7 | C |
| 8 | D |
| 9 | E |

Table 2 : user_productivity

| id | project_id | task_id | comment | date_created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 1 | p5.task1 | 2021-09-28 13:40:19 |
| 2 | 6 | 1 | p6.task1 | 2021-09-28 13:41:19 |
| 3 | 7 | 1 | p7.task1 | 2021-09-28 13:42:19 |
| 4 | 8 | 1 | p8.task1 | 2021-09-28 13:43:19 |
| 5 | 5 | 2 | p5.task2 | 2021-09-28 13:44:19 |
| 6 | 6 | 2 | p6.task2 | 2021-09-28 13:45:19 |
| 7 | 7 | 2 | p7.task2 | 2021-09-28 13:46:19 |
| 8 | 8 | 2 | p8.task2 | 2021-09-28 13:47:19 |

Table 3 : task_list

| id | project_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 8 |
| 5 | 9 |

My question is how to join two tables and show query column 'comment' is only the last update or DESCENDING from column 'date_created'.
Please Help To solved my problem with this condition. Thank you very much in advance. Cheers!

```
SELECT project_list.id, project_list.name, user_productivity.project_id, 
        user_productivity.comment, user_productivity.date_created 
FROM project_list 
    LEFT JOIN user_productivity ON project_list.id = user_productivity.project_id 
GROUP BY project_list.id
```

| No | id (on table project_list) | name | comment | date_created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | A | p5.task1 | 2021-09-28 13:40:19 |
| 2 | 6 | B | p6.task1 | 2021-09-28 13:41:19 |
| 3 | 7 | C | p7.task1 | 2021-09-28 13:42:19 |
| 4 | 8 | D | p8.task1 | 2021-09-28 13:43:19 |
| 5 | 9 | E |  |  |

The result is : group id is solved. but comment not last updated date_created

I also try :

```
SELECT project_list.id, project_list.name, user_productivity.project_id, 
        user_productivity.comment, user_productivity.date_created 
FROM project_list 
    LEFT JOIN user_productivity ON project_list.id = user_productivity.project_id 
ORDER BY unix_timestamp(user_productivity.date_created) desc
```

| No | id (on table project_list) | name | comment | date_created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | A | p5.task2 | 2021-09-28 13:44:19 |
| 2 | 6 | B | p6.task2 | 2021-09-28 13:45:19 |
| 3 | 7 | C | p7.task2 | 2021-09-28 13:46:19 |
| 4 | 8 | D | p8.task2 | 2021-09-28 13:47:19 |
| 5 | 5 | A | p8.task1 | 2021-09-28 13:43:19 |
| 6 | 6 | B | p7.task1 | 2021-09-28 13:42:19 |
| 7 | 7 | C | p6.task1 | 2021-09-28 13:41:19 |
| 8 | 8 | D | p5.task1 | 2021-09-28 13:40:19 |
| 9 | 9 | E |  |  |

The result is 'comment' is solved but group id show all query

The result I want :

| No | id (on table project_list) | name | comment | date_created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | A | p5.task2 | 2021-09-28 13:44:19 |
| 2 | 6 | B | p6.task2 | 2021-09-28 13:45:19 |
| 3 | 7 | C | p7.task2 | 2021-09-28 13:46:19 |
| 4 | 8 | D | p8.task2 | 2021-09-28 13:47:19 |
| 5 | 9 | E |  |  |

Comment: You want to left join instead of inner join to keep records from project_list that have no matching record in project_list.

Comment: Ok great. With left join is solved.

Comment: how to show 'comment' with that condition ?
I want 'comment' only show with order by 'date_created' Desc

Comment: SELECT project_list.id, project_list.name, user_productivity.project_id, user_productivity.comment, user_productivity.date_created

FROM project_list

INNER JOIN user_productivity ON project_list.id = user_productivity.project_id
GROUP BY project_list.id

Comment: the result is 'comment' show with date_Created not last update (example: p5.task1 2021-09-28 13:40:19 not  p5.task2 2021-09-28 13:44:19)

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing

Comment: i have already updated the clarification. existing result is 'comment' with date_created not last update.

I want 'comment' with date_created last update

Please help. Thank You very much

Comment: Please Help i've already update the clarification existing result. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazing! Thank you very much for your help.
Yes. need another table to join all connection. i put id from table task_list where task_id on user_productivity table is id on table task_list(see table 3 : task_list my clarification on my question)

```
SELECT project_list.id, project_list.name, user_productivity.project_id, user_productivity.comment, user_productivity.date_created, project_list.claim_no, project_list.claim_status, project_list.assigned_user
FROM project_list 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(ID) as ID, project_id FROM user_productivity GROUP BY project_id) task_list ON task_list.project_id = project_list.id 
LEFT JOIN user_productivity ON user_productivity.id = task_list.id GROUP BY project_list.id
```

Answer (score 1):

This Problem is not really solvable without more input, imagine your input table would user_productivity table would look like

| id | project_id | task_id | comment | date_created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 1 | p5.task1 | 2021-09-28 13:40:19 |
| 2 | 5 | 2 | p6.task2 | 2021-09-28 13:40:19 |
| 3 | 5 | 3 | p6.task3 | 2021-09-28 13:38:19 |

So for project_id 5 which is the last updated date with which corresponding comment?
You would need to either define a unique constraint on project_id and date_created so you wouldn't be able to have two comments with the same date_created on a project or you would need to say, e.g. I always want to use the date_created and comment which got inserted last and the ID is auto increment.

Instead of joining to your user_productivity table you need to join to a representation of the data that only contains project_id and the last update date

You would get this by

```
SELECT project_id, MAX(date_created) as date_created FROM user_productivity GROUP BY project_id
```

This results in
| project_id | date_created |
|------------|--------------|
|5| 2021-09-28 13:44:19 |
|6| 2021-09-28 13:45:19 |
|7| 2021-09-28 13:46:19 |
|8| 2021-09-28 13:47:19|

But in this case you are missing the comment column from the user_productivity group, while you could just join again to user_productivity on project_id and date_created, and if you have e.g. a unique constraint on project_id and date_created I would go for this, but if not you could have multiple rows that match that project_id and date_created.

If you know that e.g. always the biggest ID in user_productivity is the newest, because of e.g. autoincrement you could also first join to

```
SELECT MAX(ID) as ID, project_id FROM user_productivity GROUP BY project_id
```

Which would result in

| ID | project_id |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 |
| 7 | 7 |
| 8 | 8 |

That you could join now again to user_productivity based on the ID and get all the columns you need.

```
SELECT project_list.id, project_list.name, user_productivity.project_id, 
    user_productivity.comment, user_productivity.date_created 
FROM project_list
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(ID) as ID, project_id FROM user_productivity GROUP BY project_id) helper 
    ON helper.project_id = project_list.id
LEFT JOIN user_productivity ON user_productivity.id = helper.id 
GROUP BY project_list.id
```